# How to generate dynamic paths, resp possible parameter values in swagger that are generated at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a Web Api with url template: 'TestEmail/Render/{templateName}' where possible values for templateName parameter are determined at runtime using reflection.

```
public class TestEmailController : Controller
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> AllNotificationTypes =>
       typeof(INotification).Assembly.GetTypes()
           .Where(t => typeof(INotification).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract);

    [HttpGet("[controller]/{templateName}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Render(string templateName)
    {
        Type templateType = AllNotificationTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == templateName);
        if (templateType == null) return NotFound();
        string renderedHtml = ...
        return Content(renderedHtml, "text/html");
    }   
}
```

How do I reflect the possible values in swagger file using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore?

---

**EDIT**: Inspired by HelperSepu's answer, I ended up with:

```
[SwaggerOperationFilter(typeof(TemplateNameOperationFilter))]
[HttpGet("[controller]/{templateName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Render(string templateName)
{ 
....


public class TemplateNameOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var param = (PartialSchema)operation.Parameters.First(o => o.Name == "templateName");
        param.Enum = TestEmailController.AllNotificationTypes.Select(type => (object)type.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it was me I would put it in the description, but don't go crazy, just put a few examples, not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about this, and a nice option will be to put then as an enum using an IDocumentFilter

```
public class MyDocFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
  public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
  {
    PathItem path = swaggerDoc.Paths.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("TestEmail")).First().Value;
    var p = (NonBodyParameter)path.Get.Parameters.Where(x => x.Name == "templateName").First();
    p.Enum = new List<object>();
    foreach (var item in TestEmailController.AllNotificationTypes.Select(x => x.Name))
    {
      p.Enum.Add(item);
    }
  }
}
```

And that will change the UI to show a dropdown:
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. I was hoping there will be something like Attribute, (see [DynamicDataAttribute and DataTestMethodAttribute](https://www.meziantou.net/2018/02/05/mstest-v2-data-tests#using-dynamicdata) in MS Test framework).

Comment: @Liero I guess you could leverage those attributes in your `IDocumentFilter` but no swashbuckle does not have anything like that built in yet, but remember it is OpenSource you can submit a PR